# Android: Should I add an empty constructor to a fragment used in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm making a layout, similar to Google play's. I'm using a ViewPager which requires fragments. I'm getting a little confused now because some sites say that a fragment requires an empty constructor, but the example on developer.android.com doesn't contain a constructor. There code is just like this:

```
public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

So is it required to include a constructor in a fragment or can I just leave out the constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java compiler automatically adds a default no-args constructor (which is the "empty constructor" you refer to in the question) to any class that does not feature a constructor.

The following empty class:

```
public class A {
}
```

is equivalent to the following class with a no-args constructor with an empty body:

```
public class A {

    public A() {
    }

}
```

You are required to explicitly add a no-args constructor only when including another constructor with one or more arguments, because in this case the compiler does not add it for you.

Comment: Okay, so it won't make a difference if I add an empty constructor?

Comment: It won't make any difference if you add a no-args constructor with an empty body.

Comment: And what do you mean by "only when including another constructor with one or more arguments". Is that only for constructors of the fragment class or also for constructors of for example an ASyncTask inside the fragment?

Comment: Requirement holds for fragment classes (that's what you state in your question) because they need to be automatically recreated by the system, which needs/uses a no-args constructor to do it. You need to manage `AsyncTask`s yourself, so you are free to design their constructors as you see fit.

Comment: I'm sorry. My comment was a little vague. What I mean is: If the fragment contains for example an `AsyncTask` which has a constructor. Does that make it necessary to add an empty constructor to the fragment?

Comment: The existence of a constructor in any other class with no inheritance relationship with the fragment (e.g. the `AsyncTask` contained in the fragment) does not affect the number or shape of constructors that the fragment class can or must include.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not add any constructor then calling a constructor will refer to the super constructor (the same as creating an empty constructor). But if you'll create any other constructor (not desired with Fragments, do whatever you want to do in onCreate, your fragment will not be always instantiated with it sometimes the system will instantiate the fragment and the empty constructor will be called) than you need to provide also an empty one.

Comment: You should not use constructors besides empty constructor for fragments. Instead use instantiation pattern.

Comment: …Unless you want to pass a complex object that would take way more computing power to serialize and deserialize into a Bundle…